# How can I concat two strings to update a column in a postgres table using trigger function

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, string-concatenation, postgresql-triggers

I have user table and profile table. When a record is created in user table, it automatically create a record in profile table with the returned id.
The profile table is like:

```
create table app_public.profiles (
  user_id int not null primary key references users,
  first_name       text check (char_length(first_name) < 50),
  last_name        text check (char_length(last_name) < 50),
  display_name text
);
```

When a user update the profile table and enter values for `first_name` and `last_name`, I want a trigger function to concat the two columns and use the result to update `display_name`.

Currently I define the trigger function as

```
create function app_public.tg_user_display_name() returns trigger as $$
begin
  NEW.display_name = CONCAT(profiles.first_name || ' ' || NEW.profiles.last_name);
  return NEW;
end;
$$ language plpgsql volatile set search_path from current;
```

Also I have the trigger as

```
create trigger _500_update_display_name
  before update on app_public.profiles
  for each row
  execute procedure app_public.tg_user_display_name();
```

Comment: 1) Why do this at all? Just do it when you query the table. 2) If you want to do this then it is `NEW.first_name` and `NEW.last_name`.  `NEW` only holds values for the table the trigger is on as `NEW.<column_name>`.

Comment: If an answer solved your problem please accept it. Accepting an answer helps later questioners having the same issue. Further it removes the question from the unanswered queue. If none were sufficient to solve your issue please post what remains.

Comment: I have accepted the 2nd answer below

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way. Rather that creating a check constraint to enforce a size check just put that limit on the definition. Further the best way to handle NULL for either name is to just not allow it. so define Profiles as:

```
create table  profiles (
   user_id      integer     not null primary key  
 , first_name   varchar(49) not null
 , last_name    varchar(49) not null 
 , display_name text  
);
```

If you have a newer Postgres version (v12 or greater) you can eliminate the the trigger function and the trigger altogether. Define `display_name` as a [generated column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html). Then just forget about it, except Select there nothing you do with it anyway.

```
create table  profiles (
   user_id      integer     not null primary key  
 , first_name   varchar(49) not null
 , last_name    varchar(49) not null 
 , display_name text generated always as (first_name || ' ' || last_name) stored 
);
```

See the difference in the following examples:

[Profile with Trigger](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=77377059238ff1def20975a1927f0f65). Note: This will require the trigger to fire on both Insert and Update. Otherwise an Update will do what you tell it to.

[Profile with Generated Column](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=24fb553f943cdda16e20c1a1c56012e6). Note: Insert and Update will do what you wait it do.

Comment: the 2nd approach with generated column work perfectly for my use case. I tested it on my Graphql query and it was perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

it is not clear what is wrong. Your tigger function looks like good. A small problem is using [CONCAT()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) function together [string concatenation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL) operator.

```sql
SELECT 'Jon' || ' ' || 'Dir', concat('Jon' , ' ' , 'Dir')
```

Use RAISE NOTICE or RAISE EXCEPTION for debugging.